# Firebase Realtime - Transaction with additional variables

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database

So I know how to use transaction to increment or decrement a number. But how do I know who sends this number?

For example, there's a plate of cookies and everyone grab one, almost if not at the same time. How do I get the person's id or name that grabs the last cookie?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's nothing built into the SDK or product for this, so you'll have to build it yourself on top of those. For example, if you:

- Have every user write their name/UID when they grab a cookie.
- Reject writes in security rules when there are no cookies left.

Then:

- The name/UID that is in the database once no cookies are left will be the person who grabbed the last cookie.

There are many variations possible on this scheme, so pick whatever meets your use-case. The important thing is that you'll need to write the user name/UID in addition to their action.

Comment: Awesome. I figured half of this which was to send their UID. The reject writes is so cleaver. In additional to this, I'll also want to send rewards to whoever grabs the last cookie. To check this I'm thinking to have the client attach listener at the cookies/count when it changes to 0 and if it matches the user's UID then it hands out the rewards. Or do you think I should let Cloud Functions handle this? 
Thanks!

Comment: If you do it client-side, it can be spoofed by malicious users. But you can again use security rules to prevent abuse; if we continue the same example, you could have it validate that only the person whose username is stored (and the cookie count is 0) to claim (write) the reward.